# Android Dev: Parsing a XML file

Tags: java, android, xml

Here is a snippet from the XML file I am trying to parse:

```
<Item xsi:type="TextureItem" Name="Texture_0044" Visible="true">
    <Position>
        <X>240</X>
        <Y>432</Y>
    </Position>
    <CustomProperties>
        <Property Name="type" Type="string" Description="slot_rectangle">
            <string />
        </Property>
    </CustomProperties>
    <Rotation>0</Rotation>
    <Scale>
        <X>1</X>
        <Y>1</Y>
    </Scale>
    <TintColor>
        <R>255</R>
        <G>255</G>
        <B>255</B>
        <A>255</A>
        <PackedValue>4294967295</PackedValue>
    </TintColor>
</Item>
```

I'm using an XmlResourceParser object to parse the XML file and here is my code so far:

```
XmlResourceParser xrp = context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.level_1);

int eventType = xrp.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
        //System.out.println("Start document");
    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        //System.out.println("Start tag "+xrp.getName());
        if (xrp.getName().equals("Item")) {
            //...
        }
    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        //System.out.println("End tag "+xrp.getName());
    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
        //System.out.println("Text "+xrp.getText());
    }
    eventType = xrp.next();
}
System.out.println("End document");
xrp.close();
```

What I'm trying to do is have it so that every time a Item tag is found it will get the "Description" value of the Property tag, the text values of the X and Y tags inside the Position tag, and the text value of the Rotation tag and nothing more.

Right now I'm considering where it says *if (xrp.getName().equals("Item"))* just copying and pasting the outside parsing code to the inside of that if condition and then going up and down in levels getting the values I want until the END_TAG for the Item tag event occurs, but that seems very inefficient and confusing.

What I want sort of is like a xrp.Item.Position.X.getText() sort of deal if you know what I mean, does something like that exist?

Thanks!

Comment: "sort of is like a xrp.Item.Position.X.getText()". What you describe there is similar to XPath. You could look at this to see if it helps...http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp - it is supported in Android with this packahe http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html The downside is it requires the entire XML document to be loaded so if the document is large, it can cause performance problems or "out of memory" problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. Just create an object model that maps to what you expect and fill it in as you parse the XML. You'll be better off having a light-weight representation of the data instead of trying to use xpath as you need values.

Comment: Thank you, what I ended up doing was rougly the same as your solution.

Comment: Or you could use simple-XML and avoid all of this boilerplate code. Just a suggestion; it is much better. Just take a look at it.